# How to insert change only part of the value in a mysql table column

Tags: mysql

The column "path" has values that are represented in the following format:

```
http://helloworld.com/media/recordings/tape1.mp4
http://helloworld.com/media/recordings/tape2.mkv
http://helloworld.com/media/editing/tape2-a.mkv
```

how can I append a value to only file name part of the url? e.g - 20141010 (there will be only 1 date applied to all values)

```
http://helloworld.com/media/recordings/20141010tape1.mp4
http://helloworld.com/media/recordings/20141010tape2.mkv
http://helloworld.com/media/editing/20141010tape2-a.mkv
```

Can possibly use a CONCAT command but I'm not sure how to tell it to only remand entry after last /

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UPDATE table
SET path = INSERT(path, LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2, 0, '201410110');
```

See [String Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html) for the documentation of all these functions that are used to process strings.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) + 1` seems better than `LENGTH(path) - LOCATE('/', REVERSE(path)) + 2`.

Comment: You need to call `SUBSTRING_INDEX` twice, once to get the first part, another to get the last part, and then concat that with the date string. I think the result is more complicated. But maybe I'm confused, so feel free to post an answer that shows how to do it that way.

Comment: Why? `UPDATE table SET path = INSERT(path, SUBSTRING_INDEX(path, '/', -1) + 1, 0, '201410110');` should work.

Comment: `SUBSTRING_INDEX` returns the substring, not a location.

Comment: How would I reverse out the change and remove 20141010 from urls?

Comment: `REPLACE(path, '20141010', '')`